# HMS Geofencing not triggering events

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, geofencing, huawei-developers

I'm having issues trying to use `HMS Geofencing` (`React Native`). I'm setting up the service as shown below:

1. adding geofence to geofence list

```
const geofence = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        radius: radius,
        uniqueId: identifier,
        conversions:
          HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.GeofenceConstants.ENTER_GEOFENCE_CONVERSION |
          HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.GeofenceConstants.EXIT_GEOFENCE_CONVERSION,
      }
geofenceList.push(geofence)
```

2. starting geofence as explained in the documentation

```
async startGeofencingTask(): Promise<void> {
    logger.info('Starting geofencing task')
    try {
      const regions = await this.loadGeofencedPositions()
      // getting geofenceList as shown before from an array of regions
      const geofenceList = this.convertToHMSGeofenceList(regions)
      const conversionType =
        HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.GeofenceRequestConstants.ENTER_INIT_CONVERSION |
        HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.GeofenceRequestConstants.EXIT_INIT_CONVERSION
      const coordinateType = HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.GeofenceRequestConstants.COORDINATE_TYPE_WGS_84

      HMSLocation.Geofence.Native.createGeofenceList(GEOFENCING_TASK_ID, geofenceList, conversionType, coordinateType)
      HMSLocation.Geofence.Events.registerGeofenceHeadlessTask(huaweiGeofencingTask)
      HMSLocation.Geofence.Events.addGeofenceEventListener(huaweiGeofencingTask)
    } catch (error) {
      logger.warn(`Unable to start geofencing task`, error)
    }
 }
```

With this setup I'm receiving only the first trigger, but since then I'm not getting any update neither while the app is in foreground nor in background.
Any clue on why I'm getting just the initial update?

**EDIT:**
uses permissions are set as in the documentation:

```
<uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: hi@kaskeeeee, Just to confirm your question, how do you perform the test? which uses-permissions have you applied for in the manifest file? And could you pls provide screenshots of the geofence you configured on the AGC?

Comment: hi @shirley, uses permissions are set as below:
```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

i tested the geofence keeping app in foreground and background while physically driving out of and in the geofence radius.

What do you mean for geofence configuration on AGC? I only toggled the location kit

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the location permissions have been granted to the application and that you have registered a broadcast receiver in the Android Manifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".geofence.GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.huawei.hmssample.geofence.GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_LOCATION" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```